# Database Normalization for information system

Tags: database-normalization

I am currently using C# / .NET and SQLLite to create Information System. The database will consist of one table with 95 columns of user information. Is it advisable to just put all the data into 1 table? Or what should be a best practice to have a good database and in the future it will more manageable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whether 1 table is appropriate depends on information you haven't given. Your question amounts to asking for a textbook on introduction to database information modeling and database design (including normalization). Read some.

Answer (score 1):

If all the data for the User belongs together, then 95 columns could be the right approach. Put differently, your User table should reflect your User class (domain object). The main thing you should consider is whether the table is [normalized](http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html). It should be broken up if it isn't.